You cannot run CocoaPods as root. react-native ios build
So I'm using AWS Amplify with react-native and I got an error saying I couldnt use Expo go with Amplify so Im trying to build it on my local ios device but I keep getting stuck on the same error. The command im using is sudo npx expo start:ios. This is the error I keep getting.
 CocoaPods CLI not found in your PATH, installing it now.
› Attempting to install CocoaPods CLI with Gem
Successfully installed cocoapods-1.15.2
1 gem installed
› Successfully installed CocoaPods CLI with Gem
✔ Installed CocoaPods CLI.
⚠️  Something went wrong running `pod install` in the `ios` directory.
Command `pod install` failed.
└─ Cause: pod exited with non-zero code: 1
/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:439:in `help!': [!] You cannot run CocoaPods as root. (CLAide::Help)

I went over so many stackoverflow posts with similar problems but always keep getting the same error.
Also already added these 3 to my .zshrc file
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin:$PATH
export GEM_HOME="$(ruby -e 'puts Gem.user_dir')"
export PATH="$PATH:$GEM_HOME/bin"

I look forward to hearing your guys solution

Okay seems I found the answer. You should not run it with root aka sudo.
So I removed the sudo part and deleted the ios folder and that seemed to resolve the issue
